# Trying to create a json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm just learning json.  I'm trying to create an array of object Messages, The declaration does not give me a error, but when I try to access it using the following code
`serverReply2.Mesages[0].Date`, i get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

code:

```
 this.serverReply2 = {"Messages": [
    {"Date": "1/1/1",
      "Mwessage": "test messageA",
      "Attachmentsd": ["link2","link2"]},

 {"Date": "1/1/2",
      "Mwessage": "test messageB",
      "Attachmentsd": ["link2","link2"]},

 {"Date": "1/1/3",
      "Mwessage": "test messageC",
      "Attachmentsd": ["link2","link2"]},     
 ]
 };

 alert( serverReply2.Mesages[0].Date );
```

Comment: You have written Mesages instead of Messages.

Comment: And serverReply2 instead of this.serverReply2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be Messages, not Mesages

```
alert( serverReply2.Messages[0].Date );
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo, you'd better use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

A JavaScript Console (like in Firebug) will provide error messages like:

```
TypeError: serverReply2.Mesages is undefined
```

which might point you toward the typo.